# Dishwasher “finishes” in two minutes

Tags: repair, dishwasher

My Bosch dishwasher (model shx3ar7xuc) just started doing this really short cycle. I turn it on and it makes its usual whirring noise (drain pump?) for a bit then goes quiet. That’s what it’s always done. The next sound it used to make was water feeding in. Now it starts whirring again; that goes on for forty seconds or so, then the whirring stops, the dishwasher starts its wash-finished beep, and the “clean” led lights up.

The only unusual thing that happened before this started is that the water heater conked out. Tried to run the dishwasher on the cold water coming through the hot water connection and it started doing this. The hot water supply is back, but the dishwashing isn’t.

I’ve tried shutting off the power and turning it back on to reset the controls, but that didn’t help.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this? Or what I might do to try to get it working right?

Comment: Is the drain clogged ?

Comment: Are you sure you have the water running to it again? It shouldn't care about hot vs cold water. Plenty of kitchen setups don't get hot water in time to feed the dishwasher. It really sounds like it's complaining about not getting water.

Comment: In response to both comments: apparently Bosch dishwashers fail this way fairly often. There's a workaround in a YouTube video, and with that, the dishwasher runs its normal cycle. So the drain isn't clogged, and the water is getting to it.

Comment: Nice! Of course I was looking at the things which had recently changed as the most likely cause.

Answer (score 2):

There is a youtube video that shows the hack to get it to not abort the cycle.

Generally this is an error condition that the dishwasher senses a backflow condition with the water pump so it stops the cycle.

If you wait for the 2nd pause and open the door and close it again then it will clear the error and continue.

I pulled my water pump and had an elastic band wound up on the impeller.  Not too hard to pull the water pump.  Access from bottom of outside of dishwasher - I think one clip or fastener to remove and inspect.

Comment: The final paragraph seems to be the actual solution. I'm not sure why you'd want to override a safety feature.

Comment: @isherwood -- apparently this is a fairly common [failure mode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xw05iE4arZE). I don't have time now to pull the dishwasher out of the cabinet and remove the pump, so this workaround seems okay. When I get back from my trip I'll dig deeper into it. Thanks for the caution.

Comment: I've cleaned out the filters and reset the dishwasher. Still does it. The workaround in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xw05iE4arZE) gets it to run. I'll dig deeper into it when I have time a bit later. (Yes, famous last words...)

Comment: I ran the override for 2 years.  When I pulled the water pump and cleared it the first time it worked for a month and I was back to the override.  I thought doing the override for so long the first time had damaged the water pump.  When it finally refused to do anything at all after 2 years I pulled the water pump again and it had another rubber band in it...  not sure how those got in the dishwasher to start with.

Comment: Following up: I cleaned the filters, but that didn't help. I ran the dishwasher twice with this workaround, and after that it started working normally. I'm guessing there was some crud somewhere that got cleared out when the cleaned filters allowed more water to flow.

Comment: You have to be careful with the filter, if you don't screw it down properly it lets all the crud get pumped up into the spray arms and you are forever pulling bits of egg shell out of the holes in the bottom of sprayer.  Don't ask me how I know.  Also probably how the rubber bands got to the water pump from the tub!